# Prediction by neural network in R (nnet package)

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction, nnet

I can't get why the testing of dataset is not working in R neural networks (`nnet` package).

I have two datasets with similar structures - for training (`trainset`, 17 cases) and prediction (`testset`, 9 cases). Each dataset has columns: `Age`, `Gender`, `Height`, `Weight`. In the testing dataset the `age` is unknown (`NaN`).

The formula for training is obtained successfully below:

```
library(nnet)
trainednetwork<-nnet(age~gender+emLength+action5cnt,trainset, size=17)
```

Anyway, if I try to use test dataset for prediction in the next string of the code,

```
prediction<-predict(trainednetwork,testset)
```

I get mistake `"No component terms, no attribute"`. Can anyone help?

The data (obtained with `dput()` function):

- `testset`:

  ```
  structure(list(
      age = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
          NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), 
      gender = structure(
          c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
          .Label = c("f", "m"), 
          class = "factor"), 
      Height= c(9L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 9L), 
      Weight= c(1L, 41L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 29L, 12L, 6L, 12L)), 
      .Names = c("age", "gender", "Height", "Weight"), 
      class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, 9L))
  ```
- `trainset`:

  ```
  structure(list(
      age = c(43L, 35L, 22L, 28L, 20L, 47L, 41L, 23L, 
          42L, 27L, 22L, 60L, 62L, 47L, 42L, 26L, 54L), 
      gender = structure(
          c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
              2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
          .Label = c("f", "m"), 
          class = "factor"), 
      Height= c(7L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 23L, 9L, 
          9L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 7L), 
      Weight= c(2L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 28L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 40L, 
          1L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 35L)), 
      .Names = c("age", "gender", "Height", "Weight"), 
      class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, 17L))
  ```

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It seems, that nnet doesn't work with categorial data. Excluding gender data from analysis led to making neural network work.

Comment: You could have transformed the gender data into numbers and declared them as `factor` in order to include them into the modeling.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the R neuralnet package the command to use for prediction is "compute", not predict, which is very confusing. A